# convergence of sequence involving greatest integer

Tags: real-analysis

Is the sequence $$x_n=\frac{n}{3}-\big\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\big\rfloor$$ convergent?

If it is, then how do i find the limit of it?

Since $$\big\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\big\rfloor=\frac{n}{3}-\big\{\frac{n}{3}\big\}$$ we see that this is equivalent to  $$\big\{\frac{n}{3}\big\}$$what to do next?

Comment: Write out a few terms of the sequence. Does is appear convergent?

Answer (score 3):

It is not convergent since
$$x_{3k}=\frac{3k}{3}-\lfloor\frac{3k}{3}\rfloor=k-k=0 \quad \forall k$$
but
$$x_{3k+1}=\frac{3k+1}{3}-\lfloor\frac{3k+1}{3}\rfloor=k+\frac{1}{3}-k=\frac{1}{3} \quad \forall k$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Take a look at the subsequences $x_{3n}$, $x_{3n+1}$ and $x_{3n+2}$.

If $(x_n)_n$ converges, every subsequence must converge to the same limit.